# How to split consecutive elements in a list into sublists

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, split

I have the following list:

```
indices_to_remove: [0,1,2,3,..,600,800,801,802,....,1200,1600,1601,1602,...,1800]
```

I have basically 3 subsets of consecutive indices:

1. 0-600
2. 800-1200
3. 1600-1800

I would like to create 3 different small lists that will include only consecutive numbers.

Expected outcome:

```
indices_to_remove_1 : [0,1,2,3,....,600]
indices_to_remove_2 : [800,801,802,....,1200]
indices_to_remove_3 : [1600,1601,1602,....., 1800]
```

P.S: The numbers are arbitrary and random; moreover, I may encounter more than 3 subsets or less.

Comment: You want to split the lists on the gaps?

Comment: Yeah basically. Most important thing is to split the consecutive indices in one sublist @StephenRauch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is using [`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups): 
 (*used @Stephen's list for an example*):

```
import more_itertools as mit
for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices_to_remove):
    print(list(group))
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170]
```

Comment: Thanks, @anky_91 for your answer, But I would like to know if it would be possible to eliminate the first and last two elements of every sublists we created.

Comment: Thanks again. @anky_91 One last question: I would like to know if there is a way to combine all the sublists created in one big list, My main aim was to split the list into sublists and delete the first and last 5 elements, and after that to combine them in one list. Thanks again

Comment: @AlexDavies you mean `[list(group)[2:-2] for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices_to_remove)]` ??

Comment: @andy_91, yes, that's what i meant. the only issue by using this is it will create multiple sublists in one big list. For example: list =[[list 1],[list 2], [list 3]] and I would like to have one big list without minilists inside.

Comment: @AlexDavies `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([list(group)[2:-2] for group in mit.consecutive_groups(indices_to_remove)]))` , `import itertools` first

Answer (score 3):

I like to use [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) for this sort of problem.  You can do this like:

#### Split Non-Consecutive Data:

```
def split_non_consequtive(data):
    data = iter(data)
    val = next(data)
    chunk = []
    try:
        while True:
            chunk.append(val)
            val = next(data)
            if val != chunk[-1] + 1:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []
    except StopIteration:
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
```

#### Test Code:

```
indices_to_remove = (
        list(range(0, 11)) +
        list(range(80, 91)) +
        list(range(160, 171))
)

for i in split_non_consequtive(indices_to_remove):
    print(i)
```

#### Results:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]
[160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170]
```

Comment: Note that you can use `itertools.groupby` here... It's a little hard to grok but quite a neat trick: `[[el[1] for el in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(indices_to_remove), lambda L: L[1] - L[0])]` :p

Comment: @JonClements, Very Nice!

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch. However, is there any possible way to modify the code to remove the first and last three elements from every sublist produced?

Comment: `print(i[3:-3])` or `yield chunk[3:-3]`

Comment: @Stephen I vaguely remember it being an example of an `itertools` recipe in the Python 2.5 documentation or something but haven't seen it since... Just thought you might appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Without making it complicated,  you can simply solve it something like this :

```
def chunk_lists_(data_):

    consecutive_list = []

    for chunks in range(len(data_)):

        try:

            #check consecutiveness
            if data_[chunks + 1] - data_[chunks] == 1:

                #check if it's already in list
                if data_[chunks] not in consecutive_list:
                    consecutive_list.append(data_[chunks])

                #add last one too
                consecutive_list.append(data_[chunks + 1])

            else:

                #yield here and empty list
                yield consecutive_list
                consecutive_list = []
        except Exception:
            pass
    yield consecutive_list
```

> Test:

```
#Stephen's list 
print(list(chunk_lists_(list(range(0, 11)) +
        list(range(80, 91)) +
        list(range(160, 171)))))
```

> output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90], [160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170]]
```